# Excel to PDF export - page number limit

Tags: c#, excel

I am converting Excel files to PDF using C#.
Here's the code I've got so far:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(infile, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outfile);
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
excelApp.SaveWorkspace();
excelApp.Quit();
```

That part works but sometimes I have a file with more than let's say 20 columns, and the output "breaks" into multiple pages on the PDF.

Is there any way to control how many "breaks" I want to allow?

eg.
let's say the sheet has 25 column
I put in a number eg. 3
first 5 columns print on the 1st page
next 5 columns print on the 2st page
next 5 columns print on the 3st page
and the execution stops (or continues to the next sheet)

I think the answer is somewhere in this (but I'm not quite sure):

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet).PageSetup.Pages
```

Comment: You'll need to organize the page breaks to get the layout you want.  Try recording a macro in excel while setting up the layout: that should give you a good starting point for your C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this via the PageSetup class and select the appropriate PrintArea.  For PDF conversion we use the 'FitToPages' feature to zoom the view so that each worksheet occupies only a single page wide.

```
_Workbook document = application.Workbooks.Open(FileName,
                     oFalse, oTrue, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
                     oMissing, oMissing, oFalse, oFalse, oMissing, oFalse,
                     oFalse, oFalse);

foreach (Worksheet ws in document.Worksheets.OfType<Worksheet>())
{
    ws.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    ws.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
    ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
}

document.ExportAsFixedFormat(fxFormat, fileName,
                             oMissing, oMissing, oFalse, oMissing,
                             oMissing, oFalse, oMissing);
```

Or you can set the print area instead of zooming:

```
    // Specified in the same range format as the UI
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "a1-e50";
```

You may need to obtain the used columns and rows from the ws.[UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property to supply the correct print area.  Make sure when you call 'ExportAsFixedFormat' you provide false for the IgnorePrintAreas parameter.

Comment: I've found that you must only pass true for the IgnorePrintArea parameter if you explicitly set the PrintArea you want to use. If the print area has been set to a subset of cells by someone using the thick client application, and you use this code to set the page layout, you want to ignore the print area so that the whole document prints with the zooming set to one page wide